# deployment throwing error for init container only when I add a second regular container to my deployment

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, sonarqube, init

Hi There I am currently trying to deploy sonarqube 7.8-community in GKE using a DB cloudsql instance.

This requires 2 containers ( one for sonarqube and the other for the cloudproxy in order to connect to the DB)

Sonarqube container, however, also requires an init container to give it some special memory requirments.

When I create the deployment with just the sonarqube image and the init container it works fine but this wont be of any use as I need the cloudsql proxy container to connect to my external db. When I add this container though the deployment suddenly errors with the below

```
deirdrerodgers@cloudshell:~ (meta-gear-306013)$ kubectl create -f initsonar.yaml
The Deployment "sonardeploy" is invalid:spec.template.spec.initContainers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "init-sysctl"
```

This is my complete yaml file with the init container and the other two containers. I wonder is the issue because it doesnt know which container to apply the init container to?

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   labels:
     app: sonardeploy
   name: sonardeploy
   namespace: sonar
 spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: sonardeploy
   strategy: {}
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: sonardeploy
     spec:
       initContainers:
         - name: init-sysctl
           image: busybox:1.32
           imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
           securityContext:
             privileged: true
           resources:
            {}
           command: ["sh",
                     "-e",
                     "/tmp/scripts/init_sysctl.sh"]
           volumeMounts:
             - name: init-sysctl
               mountPath: /tmp/scripts/
       volumes:
       - name: init-sysctl
         configMap:
           name: sonarqube-sonarqube-init-sysctl
           items:
             - key: init_sysctl.sh
               path: init_sysctl.sh
     spec:
       containers:
       - image: sonarqube:7.8-community
         name: sonarqube
         env:
           - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME
             valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: sonarsecret
               key: username
           - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD
             valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: sonarsecret
               key: password
           - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL
             value: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonar
         ports:
           - containerPort: 9000
             name: sonarqube
       - name: cloudsql-proxy
         image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
         command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                   "-instances=meta-gear-306013:us-central1:sonardb=tcp:5432",
                   "-credential_file=/secrets/service_account.json"]
         securityContext:
           runAsNonRoot: true
         volumeMounts:
         - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials-volume
           mountPath: /secrets/
           readOnly: true
       volumes:
       - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials-volume
         secret:
           secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
```

Comment: You have two `spec:` blocks; combine them together.  Under that you should have `initContainers:`, `containers:`, and a single `volumes:` listing the two volumes (in either order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your yaml file is incorrect. You have two `spec:` blocks. It should be only one. You need to combine it together. Under `spec` block should be `initContainers` block, then `containers` and finally `volumes` block. Look at the correct yaml file below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sonardeploy
  name: sonardeploy
  namespace: sonar
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sonardeploy
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonardeploy
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-sysctl
          image: busybox:1.32
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          resources:
           {}
          command: ["sh",
                    "-e",
                    "/tmp/scripts/init_sysctl.sh"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: init-sysctl
              mountPath: /tmp/scripts/
      containers:
      - image: sonarqube:7.8-community
        name: sonarqube
        env:
          - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sonarsecret
              key: username
          - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sonarsecret
              key: password
          - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL
            value: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonar
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
            name: sonarqube
      - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                  "-instances=meta-gear-306013:us-central1:sonardb=tcp:5432",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/service_account.json"]
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials-volume
          mountPath: /secrets/
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials-volume
        secret:
          secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
      - name: init-sysctl
        configMap:
          name: sonarqube-sonarqube-init-sysctl
          items:
            - key: init_sysctl.sh
              path: init_sysctl.sh
```